# Prove $P(B|A) = P(B)$, if $A$ and $B$ are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, bayes-theorem, naive-bayes

How can I show that
$P(B|A) = P(B)$,
given that $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Comment: Write out the definition of $P(B \mid A)$. And write out the definition of independence.

Comment: (Also, to avoid down-votes and close-votes, you should provide some context in the form of where you encountered this question, what you're currently studying—as specifically as possible—and what you think might be useful to apply.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you know how a conditional probability is defined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Llease use the definitions of independent events and formula of conditional probability

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE:)

Recall the definition for independence RV. first
$$p(A,B)=p(A)p(B)$$

Then recall the equation for conditional probability
$$p(A,B)=p(B|A)p(A)$$

Taking them together, Voila, you get what you want right?

Comment: yes, got it! Thanks for the explanation!